# NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: '_get'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

full error message:

```
The following JSNoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot>#dfc82):
NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: '_get'
```

it comes from this line :             UserModel user = UserModel.fromDoc(snapshot.data); and it is in :

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: usersRef.doc(widget.userId).get(),
        builder: ( context,  snapshot) {
          List<Widget> children;
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // print('user snapshot data is: ${snapshot.data}');
            UserModel user = UserModel.fromDoc(snapshot.data);
```

model looks like :

```
factory UserModel.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return UserModel(
      id: doc.data()['id'],
      name: doc.data()['name'],
      username: doc.data()['username'],
      password: doc.data()['password'],
      profileImageUrl: doc.data()['profileImageUrl'],
      email: doc.data()['email'] ,
      userIds: doc.data()['userIds'] ?? '',
    );
  }
```

I tried downgrading the version of cloud_firestore but still don't work

Comment: Are you checked a data from snapshot in `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: have you debugged the `snapshot.data` value or `doc.data()`?

Comment: @fartem well it gives me ( Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot' )

Comment: @MuthuThavamani Idk how to do it since I can't do it in the class so I did it in the FutureBuilder and it gave me null :/

Comment: If your data can be `null`, you need to add additional check to `FutureBuilder` for handling `null` value in snapshot.

Comment: @fartem yeah I think I should be I don't know what I should put inside if it's null to try to be clean.. do you know?

Comment: you shall update your condition with null check; if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
            UserModel user = UserModel.fromDoc(snapshot.data); } else { return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ); }

Comment: @MuthuThavamani I did some debugging and snapshot.data has actually an Instance of DocumentSnapshot but what It is null is the snapshot.data.data() .. what can I do in this case pls ?

Comment: @Arb, updated in answer. i prefer to handle all `connectionstates` including `error` or else your screen would get stuck in `CircularProgressIndicator` and it's hard for user to know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error log tells, you are accessing some value on a `null` member.

It seems, the error lies in your factory method. In Flutter, to access all data from documentSnapshot in `Map<String, dynamic>` have to use `doc.data`.

Before doing that, we could check for the document existence within `DocumentSnapshot` using `doc.exists`. For further ref - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

I prefer to handle all `connectionstate` including error or else your screen would get stuck in CircularProgressIndicator and it's hard for user to know the reason.

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
     return Text("Something went wrong");
} else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
     Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data;
     return Widget;
} else {
    return Center(
     child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

Another case: If no document exists in firestore, the read (snapshot.data) will return null. However this null case internally handled by the futurebuilder `connectionState`. As per your debug result, since the `snapshot.data` has DocumentSnapshot, it didn't cause the error.

Comment: as a noobie the I didn't pass the data from another screen to it, thanks for taking time to answer this!